Ubuntu cannot communicate with NVIDIA driver
I'm running a HP zbook g9 with ubuntu 24.04 and the nvidia driver stopped working properly.
The output of nvidia-smi is:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

I installed the nvidia driver in the additional drivers menu:
"additional drivers tab"
but when i'm running modinfo nvidia | grep ^version it outputs:

modinfo: ERROR: Module nvidia not found.

The output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c) DeviceName: Onboard IGD Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller Kernel driver in use: i915


0000:01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A2000 8GB Laptop GPU] (rev a1) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GA107GLM [RTX A2000 8GB Laptop GPU] Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau 10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)

Secure boot is disabled in the BIOS.
Any idea what could be the problem and how could I resolve the issue?

Did you reboot after the driver install?  Had you tried other drivers or methods of installation? Sometimes there are leftover pieces that interfere with later installs, your cleanup must be complete, several answers on this site have details, use the search bar.  Add requested info into your original posting, no in comments, which may be deleted in the future.

It turned out the issue was a kernel update at some point in the past week.
Ubuntu 24.04 updated the kernel to version 6.10.x.
I rerolled back to kernel 6.8.x, and reinstalled all the drivers connected to NVIDIA.
Now it works.

kernel series 6.10.x isn't even offered by Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop, so it's expected it you roll your own kernel, you have all the support problems with modules that come solved with the standard offerings.
